# C# Recasting a returned HttpActionResult object and getting unable to cast object of type system.web.http.results.okNegotiatedcontentresult

Tags: c#

I am  calling a method which is

```
public IHttpActionResult GetData(int id) 
{
  ...
  List<MyData> dataList = getArrayOfRecords();
  return Ok(dataList .ToList());
}
```

In my calling method, I am trying to recast the returned array as followed

```
List<MyData> result = (List<MyData> result)myFunction.get(1);
```

I get the following error

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from your answer that you're calling "getArrayOfRecords" to get the data, you should consider refactoring all of this to allow the function returning List to be a separate function, something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetData(int id) 
{
  //now the only function of this is to wrap in an ActionResult
  List<MyData> dataList = GetDataAsList(id);
  return Ok(dataList .ToList());
}

public List<MyData> GetDataAsList(int id)
{
  ... do your work to get the information
  List<MyData> dataList = getArrayOfRecords();
  return dataList;
}
```

After doing that, now in your other location you can call:

```
List<MyData> result = GetDataAsList(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

found working code here

It seems IEnumerable with class or single anonymous are OK for such convert, but IEnumerable with anonymous does not works.

https://www.oipapio.com/question-8236144